# z-axis formatting in mplot3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to make a surface plot in matplotlib, but I am unable to make the formatting of the z-axis look good. I want it to be on scientific notation, with the prefix along the axis and the exponent above the axis (like what you usually get in matlab). At the moment I can only get the values without scientific notation (with a comma and five zeros in front), or I get the prefixes but not the exponent...

Try 1: (gives scientific notation, but not the exponent)

```
from matplotlib import ticker

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3)
formatter = ticker.ScalarFormatter()
formatter.set_scientific(True)
formatter.set_powerlimits((-2,2))
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Try 2: (gives the values on decimal form, same as default output)

```
from matplotlib import ticker

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=3, cstride=3)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis="z", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which version of matplotlib are you using?  You might be running into a bug that wasn't fixed until 1.0.1. http://old.nabble.com/Displaying-offsets-in-3d-plots-td30474615.html

Comment: @Stephen Terry: I am running 1.0.1.

`Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (32-bit)| (r271:86832, Dec  3 2010, 15:41:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.0.1'`

Answer (score 4):

When you create your `ScalarFormatter`, try the "use Math Text" parameter:

```
from matplotlib import ticker
niceMathTextForm = ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
ax.w_zaxis.set_major_formatter(niceMathTextForm)
```

Comment: useOffset=false is nice as well for scientific notation